# Adding Rice noise in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am importing an image from my PC to Matlab and my key goal is to add Rician noise. But, it doesn't work. All the time this warning appears:

> Matrix dimensions must agree.

The algorithm is going to have a later use, so dimension of images will vary. 
In this particular use, dimension of `sz1` and `sz2` is **384*1242**. Dimension of `J` is **384*414*3** `double`. `I` has the same dimension as `J`, but it's `uint8`.

Could you please give me a hint, so I could make it functional?

```
clear all; close all; clc;

I = imread('test.png');

J = double(im2uint8(I))
[sz1 sz2]=size(J);

realchannel = normrnd(0,0.5,sz1,sz2) + J; % 0.5 is the gaussian noise level
imaginarychannel = normrnd(0,0.5,sz1,sz2);
noisyimage = sqrt(realchannel.^2 + imaginarychannel.^2); % now the image has Rician distributed noise
```

Comment: Which version of MATLAB? This is probably because `size(normrnd(0,0.5,sz1,sz2))` is not the same as `size(J)`, so the matrix dimensions do not agree.

Comment: I am using R2015a version. I have put **normrnd** in front of **size** and it gives me error **To many output arguments**.

Comment: Please take some time to understand what I said and test those commands that I showed you. You can not add matrices that are not the same size!

Comment: I have tried 
    **[sz1 sz2]=normrnd(size(J)); **
and 
    **realchannel = normrnd(0,0.5,sz1,sz2) + J;**

Or
   ** [sz1 sz2]=size(J); **
and
    **realchannel = size(0,0.5,sz1,sz2) + J;**

It still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, now it works as it should.